# Money is necessary to leave the airport in Moscow for ladies

Tags: customs-and-immigration, russia, scams, weddings

I met agirl from Russia on the site of marriage and I send her a money to issue apasport , after we arrange the tickets for her and sending her 400 $ , she said that she has to have 2000$ to be with her to show this money to government in Moscow to leave her left as she said, without having this money with her she will not allowe to to leave to travel 
Should I send her the money ? Or not? Is she lying?

Comment: The question is : does any lady must have 2000$ to leave Moscow airport?

Comment: I'm a woman and I've left various Moscow airports for various destinations many times without showing any cash to anybody. Sorry but you've been scammed.

Comment: It's a scam. Your $400 is lost. **Don't** send any more money. **Do** break contact immediately.

Comment: ‘She’ might not even be a ‘she’, sadly. This is a scam. See what she says if you were to suggest you go to meet her in Russia instead.